# iOS reading list doesn't work offline

Tags: ios, safari, reading-list

When I add some webpage to my reading list (like [Medium articles](https://medium.com/), I'm not able to read them if I'm offline: I have a error telling my phone is not connected to Internet.

According to the [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200294), pages in the reading list should be accessible offline (I checked Settings > Safari > Reading List > Automatically Save Offline).

Is it a bug?

Comment: I'm using iOS 11.3.1 and it works fine for me.  I can read all the articles in my reading list when i turn off cellular and wifi and turn on airplane mode.

Answer (score 1):

**Adding something to your reading list**

1. On your desired webpage, click the share icon in the top-right

When opening something from your reading list make sure you open it at the side not in the search bar.

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6485335)

> Once you add something to your reading list you do not access it from the URL box.  You access it from the open book icon just to the right of the URL in the upper right corner of your screen.

Comment: Doesn't work on Catalina, even though the "Save articles for offline reading automatically" option exists and is ticked.